# Order by on EF not working as I had hoped

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, sql-order-by

How do I get this to work properly? I want `order by duedate desc, type`

I currently have:

```
billSummaryRepository.GetBillSummaries(logIn.CustomerNumber)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.DueDate)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Type)
```

This works:

```
BillSummaries = billSummaryRepository.GetBillSummaries(logIn.CustomerNumber)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Type)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.DueDate)
```

but how dangerous is that? Will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BillSummaries = billSummaryRepository
    .GetBillSummaries(logIn.CustomerNumber)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.DueDate)
    .ThenBy(o => o.Type);
```